# mail.log for PHP mails

Tags: php, email, exim

I got a new server. When I get a new server I always activate mail.log in php.ini. I did again too. Path is `/var/log/phpmaillog`

I restart httpd and I also created the file with

> touch /var/log/phpmaillog

But it doesn't log any email.

Server uses WHM panel and Exim MTA.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of the log file? Is it writable by the user that your php scripts run as? And/or are the the same as on your other servers?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I edited `/etc/php.ini`. The right one is `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`. Also `/var/log/phpmaillog` owner must be `nobody:nobody` and `666` permission.